# Why do I get Error 400 Bad Request "INVALID_X_API_USER_HEADER" while trying to call the AdobeSign API?

Tags: php, adobe-sign

**Introduction**:
Currently, I'm developing an app (in **laravel-backpack**) with a formulary you can check out in the next image:
[formulary_of_my_app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sf2Mr.png)

I'm trying to use the API of Adobe Sign (the objective of this app is to ease the process of signing contracts, making it automatic just by adding the PDF and clicking the "Firmar" button (Firmar = Sign), and this will send the PDF). I have everything I need (Developer Account, IntegrationKey, SecretKey, UserId, Access-Token, etc...) to call the API.

**Error I got**:
But I have this problem where It says that the "API-USER-HEADER" is invalid because the value provided is in invalid format. In the next image you check out the error:
[error_invalid_x_api_user](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W2Y2L.png)

**Php Code** (here goes the code that I'm using to call the API):

```
<?php

namespace App\Services;

use GuzzleHttp\Client;

class AdobeSign
{
    private $client;
    private $baseUrl;
    private $integrationKey;
    private $secretKey;
    private $userId;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->client = new Client();
        $this->baseUrl = "https://api.eu1.echosign.com/api/rest/v6";/*URL DE LA API*/
        $this->integrationKey = env('ADOBE_SIGN_INTEGRATION_KEY');/*De la cuenta de Adobe Sign*/
        $this->secretKey = env('ADOBE_SIGN_SECRET_KEY');/*De la cuenta de Adobe Sign*/
        $this->userId = env('ADOBE_SIGN_USER_ID');/*De la cuenta de Adobe Sign*/
    }

    private function getAuthorizationHeader()
    { 
        $headers = [
            'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' => '*',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' => 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS',
            'Authorization' => sprintf('Bearer %s', env('ADOBE_SIGN_TOKEN')),
            'x-api-user' => base64_encode(json_encode([
                'email' => 'email@domain.domain',
                'firstName' => 'name',
                'lastName' => 'secondName',
                'groupIds' => [env('ADOBE_SIGN_GROUP_ID')],
                'userId' => env('ADOBE_SIGN_USER_ID')
            ])),
        ];

        $timeStamp = time();
        //$headers['x-api-user'] = sprintf('{"userId":"%s"}', $this->userId);
        $headers['x-sdk-date'] = gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s T', $timeStamp);
        
        print_r($headers);
        echo(base64_encode(json_encode($headers)));
        //$headers['x-api-user'] = base64_encode(json_encode($headers));
        return $headers;
    }

    private function getAccessToken($timeStamp)
    {
        $jwtPayload = [
            'iss' => $this->integrationKey,
            'sub' => base64_encode(json_encode(env('ADOBE_SIGN_USER_EMAIL'))),
            'aud' => 'https://api.eu1.echosign.com',
            'exp' => $timeStamp + 3600,
            'iat' => $timeStamp
        ];

        $jwtHeader = [
            'alg' => 'HS256',
            'typ' => 'JWT'
        ];

        $jwtHeaderEncoded = base64_encode(json_encode($jwtHeader));
        $jwtPayloadEncoded = base64_encode(json_encode($jwtPayload));
        $jwtSignatureEncoded = base64_encode(hash_hmac('sha256', "$jwtHeaderEncoded.$jwtPayloadEncoded", $this->secretKey, true));

        $jwtToken = "$jwtHeaderEncoded.$jwtPayloadEncoded.$jwtSignatureEncoded";

        return $jwtToken;
    }

    public function sendAgreement($name, $email, $fileUrl, $X, $Y, $page)
    {
        $response = $this->client->post($this->baseUrl . '/agreements', [
            'headers' => $this->getAuthorizationHeader(),
            'json' => [
                'documentCreationInfo' => [
                    'fileInfos' => [/*Documento pdf INFO*/
                        [
                            'libraryDocumentId' => '',/*Se utiliza si ya esta en la biblioteca*/
                            'transientDocumentId' => '',/*Se utiliza si el archivo aún no se ha subido a la biblioteca*/
                            'documentURL' => $fileUrl,/*URL DEL ARCHIVO*/
                            'name' => $name/*nombre del archivo*/
                        ]
                    ],
                    'recipientSetInfos' => [/*Destinatario INFO*/
                        [
                            'recipientSetMemberInfos' => [/*Info, por si se quieren añadir mas de un destinatario */
                                [
                                    'email' => $email/*Email del destinatario*/
                                ]
                            ],
                            'recipientSetRole' => 'SIGNER'/*ROL DEL DESTINATARIO [SIGNER :=: Firmar el acuerdo]*/
                        ]
                    ],
                    'signatureType' => 'ESIGN', /*TIPO DE FIRMA QUE SE UTILIZARÁ [ESIGN :=: Puede firmar el acuerdo digitalmente]*/
                    'signatureFlow' => 'SENDER_SIGNATURE_NOT_REQUIRED',/*FLUJO DE LA FIRMA [SENDER_SIGNATURE_NOT_REQUIRED :=: El que lo envia necesita firmar el acuerdo]*/
                    'name' => $name,/*NOMBRE DEL ACUERDO QUE SE VA A FIRMAR */
                    'signatureFieldInfos' => [
                        [
                            'defaultValue' => '',
                            'locations' => [
                                [
                                    'height' => $Y,
                                    'left' => $X,
                                    'pageNumber' => $page,
                                    'top' => '50',
                                    'width' => '100'
                                ]
                            ],
                            'name' => 'Signature'
                        ]
                    ]
                ]
            ]
        ]);
    }
}
```

**What have I already tried?**:
I navigated a bunch of webs that related to this error and checked out the Adobe documentation, but I'm still stuck. Also, I tried changing the code (It didn't make a difference) and tested If It really responded the API in this AdobeSign [link](https://secure.eu1.adobesign.com/public/docs/restapi/v6#!/transientDocuments/createTransientDocument). When I tested in the AdobeSign link that I have provided, I got this result:
[test_adobe_sign_1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Llb1U.png) and
[test_adobe_sign_2"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2K2ss.png)

It really works as you can see in the image because is giving back the "Response Body", but in my code something is missing or I did something wrong.

Comment: The documentation says, _"The userId or email of API caller using the account or group token in the format `userid:{userId}` OR `email:{email}`."_ So why are you proving the _base64-encoded_ version of a _JSON-encoded_ array, that contains _five_ properties ...?

Comment: Hey fercor3000. Your issue has nothing to do with Backpack. Sorry can't help more here. Cheers

Comment: And `//$headers['x-api-user'] = sprintf('{"userId":"%s"}', $this->userId);` will also not produce `userid:{userId}`. It is probably reasonable to assume here that the { } are only used to symbolize, "a value needs to be inserted in this place", so I am guessing all they really want from you as the content of that header, is just `userid:12345`

Comment: The only one that is mandatory is the userid or email, the other five are optionals. But I tried just by adding the userid or email, and still appears the error.

Comment: Okay, I just tried what you said CBroe by adding "email:mail@mail.com" and the error has changed. Thank you.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Sure, sorry Yogendra for the bad formation of the question (I'm new here). I'm going to edit it right now.

Comment: Your question should remain strictly a question. If you have a solution, (roll back your latest edit and) post that as an answer, and eventually accept that answer. This is how you mark a problem as resolved on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Yes, I've already posted the answer and I will accept it. But triplee, I still don't understand if the question is well formed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE** "solution": I did not understand the Adobe Sign documentation well. The main problem was that I was writing literally userid:{userId} OR email:{email.com} when the correct way is userid:1234 OR email:email.com (you don't need the {}).

Also, I was providing a base64 encoded-version of a JSON array with 5 properties that were unnecessaries, I only needed the userid:{userId} OR email:{email}.

Thanks **CBroe** for the comments and help.

```
<?php

namespace App\Services;

use GuzzleHttp\Client;

class AdobeSign
{
    private $client;
    private $baseUrl;
    private $integrationKey;
    private $secretKey;
    private $userId;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->client = new Client();
        $this->baseUrl = "https://api.eu1.echosign.com/api/rest/v6";/*URL DE LA API*/
        $this->integrationKey = env('ADOBE_SIGN_INTEGRATION_KEY');/*De la cuenta de Adobe Sign*/
        $this->secretKey = env('ADOBE_SIGN_SECRET_KEY');/*De la cuenta de Adobe Sign*/
        $this->userId = env('ADOBE_SIGN_USER_ID');/*De la cuenta de Adobe Sign*/
    }

    private function getAuthorizationHeader()
    { 
        $headers = [
            'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' => '*',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' => 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS',
            'Authorization' => sprintf('Bearer %s', env('ADOBE_SIGN_TOKEN')),
            'x-api-user' => 'email:mail@mail.com'
        ];

        $timeStamp = time();
        $headers['x-sdk-date'] = gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s T', $timeStamp);
        
        print_r($headers);
        echo(base64_encode(json_encode($headers)));
        return $headers;
    }

    private function getAccessToken($timeStamp)
    {
        $jwtPayload = [
            'iss' => $this->integrationKey,
            'sub' => base64_encode(json_encode(env('ADOBE_SIGN_USER_EMAIL'))),
            'aud' => 'https://api.eu1.echosign.com',
            'exp' => $timeStamp + 3600,
            'iat' => $timeStamp
        ];

        $jwtHeader = [
            'alg' => 'HS256',
            'typ' => 'JWT'
        ];

        $jwtHeaderEncoded = base64_encode(json_encode($jwtHeader));
        $jwtPayloadEncoded = base64_encode(json_encode($jwtPayload));
        $jwtSignatureEncoded = base64_encode(hash_hmac('sha256', "$jwtHeaderEncoded.$jwtPayloadEncoded", $this->secretKey, true));

        $jwtToken = "$jwtHeaderEncoded.$jwtPayloadEncoded.$jwtSignatureEncoded";

        return $jwtToken;
    }

    public function sendAgreement($name, $email, $fileUrl, $X, $Y, $page)
    {
        $response = $this->client->post($this->baseUrl . '/agreements', [
            #HEADER
            'headers' => $this->getAuthorizationHeader(),
            #BODY
            'json' => [
                'documentCreationInfo' => [
                    'fileInfos' => [/*Documento pdf INFO*/
                        [
                            'libraryDocumentId' => '',/*Se utiliza si ya esta en la biblioteca*/
                            'transientDocumentId' => '',/*Se utiliza si el archivo aún no se ha subido a la biblioteca*/
                            'documentURL' => $fileUrl,/*URL DEL ARCHIVO*/
                            'name' => $name/*nombre del archivo*/
                        ]
                    ],
                    'recipientSetInfos' => [/*Destinatario INFO*/
                        [
                            'recipientSetMemberInfos' => [/*Info, por si se quieren añadir mas de un destinatario */
                                [
                                    'email' => $email/*Email del destinatario*/
                                ]
                            ],
                            'recipientSetRole' => 'SIGNER'/*ROL DEL DESTINATARIO [SIGNER :=: Firmante]*/
                        ]
                    ],
                    'signatureType' => 'ESIGN', /*TIPO DE FIRMA QUE SE UTILIZARÁ [ESIGN :=: Puede firmar el acuerdo digitalmente]*/
                    'signatureFlow' => 'SENDER_SIGNATURE_NOT_REQUIRED',/*FLUJO DE LA FIRMA [SENDER_SIGNATURE_NOT_REQUIRED :=: El que lo envia necesita firmar el acuerdo]*/
                    'name' => $name,/*NOMBRE DEL ACUERDO QUE SE VA A FIRMAR */
                    'signatureFieldInfos' => [
                        [
                            'defaultValue' => '',
                            'locations' => [
                                [
                                    'height' => $Y,
                                    'left' => $X,
                                    'pageNumber' => $page,
                                    'top' => '50',
                                    'width' => '100'
                                ]
                            ],
                            'name' => 'Signature'
                        ]
                    ]
                ]
            ]
        ]);
    }
}
```